# Caption shifting vertically in groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I am using a groupplot to create a discontinuity in the `y-axis`. However, when I'm applying the `axis x line=top` command, the caption shifts down, as shown in the screenshot attached.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Here is part of the code I am using

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2,vertical sep=0pt}]

\nextgroupplot[enable tick line clipping=false,
    ymode=log,
    width=6cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    axis line style=thick,
    axis on top=true,
    x tick style={draw=none},
    axis x line=bottom,
    xmin=1,xmax=5,
    xticklabels={,,},
    y tick style={black,thick},
    y label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0),anchor=near ticklabel},
    ymin=2e8,ymax=10^10,
    ytick={10^9,10^10},
    axis y discontinuity=parallel,
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    ylabel={resistance [\SI{}{\ohm}]},
]
    \addplot [red,thick,y=y,x=x] table {
    x       y
    1       3e9
    5       3e9
    };


\nextgroupplot[enable tick line clipping=false,
    ymode=log,
    width=6cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    axis line style=thick,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis on top=true,
    x tick style={black,thick},
    x label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.5),anchor=near ticklabel},
    xmin=1,xmax=5,
    xtick={1,2,...,5},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    xlabel={volume [\SI{}{\ml}]},
   y tick style={black,thick},
%    y label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.5),anchor=near ticklabel},
    ymin=10^3,ymax=3e4,
    ytick={10^3,10^4},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
%    ylabel={resistance [\SI{}{\ohm}]},
]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=1.8,fill=blue!30},y=y,x=x] table {
    x       y
    1       10200
    2       5730
    3       3610
    4       3030
    5       2790
    };

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lateral resistance of a single compliant electrode at different volumes of the SWCNT dispersion sprayed.}
\label{fig:resist}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that this is bug in `axis x line=top`.

Comment: The caption is unrelated (hence the retag), for some reason you get a lot of extra whitespace in the `tikzpicture` below the axes, add `\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);` just before `\end{tikzpicture}` to see that. Seems the combination of `ymode=log`, `axis y discontinuity`  and `axis x line=bottom` somehow causes this, uncomment either of them and the problem goes away.  No idea why though ...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment it seems that the combination of `ymode=log`, `axis x line=bottom`  (or `top`) and `axis discontinuity` causes a lot of extra whitespace to be added to the bottom of the diagram. The `ymin`/`ymax` setting in the first axis makes it worse. The caption has nothing to with the problem really, that is added where it should be, right below the `tikzpicture`. The problem is that the `tikzpicture` is too big. Add

```
\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
```

just before `\end{tikzpicture}` to see that. No idea exactly what causes this though. I've reported it at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/432

In the meantime you can as a workaround draw the discontinuity symbols manually, e.g. by adding `group name=P` in the `group style` and drawing a `double` line in each lower corner of the top axis with

```
\draw [double, thick, double distance=3pt] (P c1r1.south west) ++(-8pt, 0) -- +(16pt,0);
\draw [double, thick, double distance=3pt] (P c1r1.south east) ++(-8pt, 0) -- +(16pt,0);
```

Remove the `axis discontinuity` option from the axis options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
     group size=1 by 2,
     vertical sep=0pt,
     group name=P
     }
  ]

\nextgroupplot[enable tick line clipping=false,
    ymode=log,
    width=6cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    axis line style=thick,
    axis on top=true,
    x tick style={draw=none},
    axis x line=top,
    xmin=1,xmax=5,
    xticklabels={,,},
    y tick style={black,thick},
    y label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0),anchor=near ticklabel},
    ymin=2e8,ymax=10^10,
    ytick={10^9,10^10},
%    axis y discontinuity=parallel,
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    ylabel={resistance [\SI{}{\ohm}]},
]
    \addplot [red,thick,y=y,x=x] table {
    x       y
    1       3e9
    5       3e9
    };


\nextgroupplot[
    enable tick line clipping=false,
    ymode=log,
    width=6cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    axis line style=thick,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis on top=true,
    x tick style={black,thick},
    x label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.5),anchor=near ticklabel},
    xmin=1,xmax=5,
    xtick={1,2,...,5},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    xlabel={volume [\SI{}{\ml}]},
   y tick style={black,thick},
    y label style={at=(ticklabel cs:0.5),anchor=near ticklabel},
    ymin=10^3,ymax=3e4,
    ytick={10^3,10^4},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
%    ylabel={resistance [\SI{}{\ohm}]},
]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=1.8,fill=blue!30},y=y,x=x] table {
    x       y
    1       10200
    2       5730
    3       3610
    4       3030
    5       2790
    };

\end{groupplot}

\draw [double, thick, double distance=3pt] (P c1r1.south west) ++(-8pt, 0) -- +(16pt,0);
\draw [double, thick, double distance=3pt] (P c1r1.south east) ++(-8pt, 0) -- +(16pt,0);
\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lateral resistance of a single compliant electrode at different volumes of the SWCNT dispersion sprayed.}
\label{fig:resist}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Torbjørn. I did solve the problem by adding the discontinuity manually and it works. But I was keen to find out what was wrong with my code. By the way, adding `\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);` did visualise it.

Comment: @Gagik There might not be anything wrong with *your* code, it could be a bug with e.g. the `axis discontinuity` implementation in `pgfplots`.

Comment: I got it. Just out of curiosity, are these bugs fixable? If so, who it and how?

Comment: @Gagik As I said in my answer, there is an issue tracker on GitHub where bugs can be reported. If it is a bug, then it probably can be fixed by the current maintainer, but depending on the cause it might not be easy I suppose … I can report it later today if you like.

Comment: Gotcha @Torbjørn. Please, do report. Appreciate it.